# Consider adding descriptive popups for parts of the body that are mentioned in answers in latin

Tags: feature-request

As a non specialist I would strongly suggest a way to anatomically show the mentioned parts of the body in optional popups maybe, that appear when user hovers over the given latin term. Otherwise we - regular people struggle to understand the text.

If system allows plugins/addons, I could arrange that as web developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would require changes to the entire stackexchange web site. It's not something we can implement here. If you really want to see such a change implemented, you need to raise the question on https://meta.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks and I should say that I've found a way. Now only if you could help me to find a good (preferably open source), online, interactive anatomy atlas, I could help to integrate it into this QA instance.